# Correlation between predictor variables in an AIC model

Tags: correlation, multinomial-distribution, aic

I'm using multinomial logistic regression analysis to analyse deer behavioural responses to camera traps based on 7 predictor variables.

I have 2 models which are very close together in AIC value (season AIC 1005.103; season and percentage cover 1005.023). Season and percentage cover is the best model (but only nominally).

Percentage cover is defined as the percentage of the deer covered by topographical features and vegetation relative to the camera. It has an AIC value of 1008.289 when considered alone. However, season and cover appear to be closely correlated (which makes sense). I am wondering if it is redundant to use both variables in the same model or is a certain level of correlation okay?

Thanks a mil

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The correlation is not going to be ok if your goal is to describe how much of the response variance is explained by each factor. Also, if we consider Season and (Season, Percentage) models, their Akaike weights are virtually the same (one is over 0.49, and the other one is below 0.51). It looks like you'll be better off with Season only model.